# BigQuery - Deterministic UUID

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a UUID for a derivative data model and an entity that doesn't have it on its own.

`GENERATE_UUID()` will give me different value every time I run it but I was looking for something that could use existing attributes of the entity.

So far I did this

```
SELECT
  MD5(SHA512(CONCAT(<attr1>, <attr2>)))
```

I know using MD5 on its own is insecure but if I hash it with SHA512 first, is it a viable solution? Or in terms of security, because it's deterministic, based on data, and not completely random, it wouldn't be safe?

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of hashing algorithms like `MD5` and `SHA512` to generate a **UUID-like** value based on existing attributes of an entity can be a viable solution in certain contexts. However, there are some considerations to keep in mind regarding security and uniqueness.

Using a deterministic method like hashing based on existing attributes means that if the input attributes are the same, the output UUID-like value will also be the same. This can be advantageous for consistency and reproducibility but may not provide the same level of uniqueness as a true UUID.

While combining hashing algorithms can enhance security to some extent, it's important to note that MD5 is considered cryptographically broken and should not be relied upon for security-critical applications. SHA512 is more secure but using it in combination with MD5 doesn't fully mitigate the weaknesses of MD5.

Although the likelihood of collisions (two different inputs producing the same output) is reduced when using multiple hash functions, it's still a possibility, especially if the input space is limited or predictable. This means that while the generated values may be sufficiently unique for your specific use case, they may not have the same level of guaranteed uniqueness as true UUIDs.

In summary, while using a combination of hashing algorithms like MD5 and SHA512 can provide a UUID-like value based on existing attributes, it's essential to carefully consider the trade-offs in terms of security, uniqueness, and performance for your specific use case. Additionally, it's recommended to evaluate alternative approaches to UUID generation to ensure that your solution meets your requirements effectively.